# how to get stored procedure xml return raw format using .net OledbCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, oledb

I am having a problem getting the XML return from stored procedure (on SQL Server 2008R2).

The stored procedure is very simple with one statement to return XML data.

e.g.

```
SELECT 1 a FOR XML RAW
```

We need to use oledb in C# to call the stored procedure and get the xml.

The `ExecuteReader` return is getting a byte array for the xml return, and I am having problem 'decoding' that back to the xml. I have tried all the different types of encoding in .net e.g.

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
```

However, none of them work.

If I switch to `SqlConnection` instead of oledb connection and call the stored procedure in .net, it is working fine. I can get the return in string format successfully (instead of byte array)

According to this, returning a byte array when calling the stored procedure in oledb is expected, I am just having trouble converting the `byte[]` back to the original xml in .net.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/04/13/576095.aspx

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Comment: If `SqlConnection` works - why aren't you just using that, instead of insisting on the `OleDbConnnection` ??

Comment: Does the [answer posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100830/read-xml-from-sql-server-using-oledbdatareader) help?  I can't test this at the moment.

Comment: @MarkE Not, it doesn't work, i have tried that, the tostring is not giving me the xml format string, and it throw exception while trying to load the xml

Comment: @marc_s I hear you:-) We have to use the oledbconnection for some other reason, and we cannot change that. unfortunately. There was a long discussion before for that...

Comment: Are you allowed to change the stored procedure or does it have to stay as is?

Comment: Have you tried `ExecuteXmlReader()` and `XmlReader` with `SqlConnection`?